# Getting Empty Object during Put request to the server

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongodb, express, mongoose

I created an API for following and followers user for Social Media Application, while request from postman getting empty object: `{}` But it seems to me to be correct.

Model:

```
const mongoose = require("mongoose");

const UserSchema = mongoose.Schema({
  username: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  password: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  firstname: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  lastname: {
    type: String,
    required: true,
  },
  isAdmin: {
    type: Boolean,
    default: false,
  },
  profilePicture: String,
  coverPicture: String,
  about: String,
  livesin: String,
  workAt: String,
  relationship: String,
  followers: [],
  following: []
},{
    timestamps:true
}
);

const UserModel = mongoose.model("Users", UserSchema);

module.exports = UserModel;
```

UserControler:

```
const UserModel = require("../Models/Usermodel");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");

const followUser = async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id.trim();
  const { currentUserId } = req.body;

  if (currentUserId === id) {
    res.status(403).send("Action forbiden");
  } else {
    try {
      const followUser = await UserModel.findById(id);
      const followingUser = await UserModel.findById(currentUserId);

      if (!followUser.followers.includes(currentUserId)) {

        await followUser.updateOne({ $push: { followers: currentUserId } });
        await followingUser.updateOne({ $push: { following: id } });
        res.status(200).send({message:"User Followed"});
      } else {
        res.status(403).send("User alredy followed by you!");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error);
    }
  }
};

module.exports = { getUser, updateUser, userDelete, followUser };
```

UserRoute:

```
const express = require("express");
const {getUser,updateUser, userDelete, followUser} = require("../Controller/userControler");

const router = express.Router()

router.get("/:id",getUser)
router.put("/:id",updateUser)
router.delete("/:id", userDelete)
router.put("/:id/follow", followUser)

module.exports=router;
```

index.js:

```
app.use("/user",UserRoute)
```

Here is the complete details regarding the error, let me know what happens in the code, thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

i assume that you have all the other functions other than followUser in your `controller.js`

The thing is that you must first specify the field name on the basis of which you want to update the document.
Here is what you need to do;

```
const UserModel = require("../Models/Usermodel");
const bcrypt = require("bcryptjs");
const mongoose = require("mongoose");//updated line

const followUser = async (req, res) => {
  const id = req.params.id.trim();
  const { currentUserId } = req.body;

  if (currentUserId === id) {
    res.status(403).send("Action forbiden");
  } else {
    try {
      const followUser = await UserModel.findById({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)});
      const followingUser = await UserModel.findById({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(currentUserId)});

      if (!followUser.followers.includes(currentUserId)) {

        await followUser.updateOne({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(*id of the user you want to update*)},{ $push: { followers: currentUserId } });
        await followingUser.updateOne({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(*id of the user you want to update*)}{ $push: { following: id } });
        res.status(200).send({message:"User Followed"});
      } else {
        res.status(403).send("User alredy followed by you!");
      }
    } catch (error) {
      res.status(500).send(error);
    }
  }
};

module.exports = { getUser, updateUser, userDelete, followUser };
```

And while hitting the api pls make sure that your route should be

```
localhost:port-number/user/12345789/follow
```

and also make sure that the API type in postman must be same as in the backend e.g; **PUT**

Comment: its not worked :

Comment: try {
      const followUser = await UserModel.findById({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)});
      const followingUser = await UserModel.findById({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(currentUserId)});

      if (!followUser.followers.includes(currentUserId)) {

        await followUser.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(followUser)},{ $push: { followers: currentUserId } });
        await followingUser.findByIdAndUpdate({_id: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(followingUser)},{ $push: { following: id } });
        res.status(200).send({message:"User Followed"});
      } else {

Comment: scenario is Two user want to follow each other

Comment: still getting empty object

Comment: i have updated the answer u can test now if issue still remains then you need to add all the files in your question and add ss of the postman also then i can do something about it

Comment: **ok** adding all the files check it out

Comment: yep now it's working, mistake was i didn't required moongose on file **const mongoose = require("mongoose");**  thanks man.

Comment: now the problem is message is success **res.status(200).send({message:"User Followed"});** but follow ID doesn't **push** in to Follower ID

Comment: make sure the push object or whatever the value is must match the values already present in the array in db:
i.e: 
{$push: {following: mongoose.Types.ObjectId(id)}}
and also in your schema double check that following is an array or not!
Also you can visit the mongodb website for refrence : https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/update/push/

Comment: Yep now its working completely fine, Thanks Man!

Answer (score 0):

please try findByIdAndUpdate query insted of using updateOne

Comment: Yep i did but it,s was remain same